# how to change table rows by using tab key

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2, ognl

i want to change table row when i pressing the tab key.Here i am using struts tag.is there any idea please post...

```
<s:iterator value="addresslist">
   <tr>
     <td><s:property value="id" /></td>
     <td><s:property value="name" />,<s:property value="cprNo" />,<s:property value="address" />,<s:property value="district" />,<s:property value="state" /></td>
     <td><s:property value="age" /></td>
  </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "change table row"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<s:set var="count" value="0"/>
<s:iterator value="addresslist">
   <tr>
     <td><span tabindex="<s:property value="%{#count}"/>"><s:property value="id" /></span></td>
     <td><span tabindex="<s:property value="%{#count+1}"/>"><s:property value="name" />,<s:property value="cprNo" />,<s:property value="address" />,<s:property value="district" />,<s:property value="state" /></span></td>
     <td><span tabindex="<s:property value="%{#count+2}"/>"><s:property value="age" /></span></td>
  </tr>
  <s:set var="count" value="%{#count+3}"/>
</s:iterator>
```

**References:**

- [How to make an element focusable with `tabindex`](http://snook.ca/archives/accessibility_and_usability/elements_focusable_with_tabindex)